# Detecting if navigator.vibrate can be called

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, touch-event

I noticed recently an error popup in Chrome telling that navigator.vibrate can only be called once the user interacted with the page:

[image: Chrome vibrate error popup]

I could change my page to ask for user interaction (with a button for example) but I'd rather keep my page as is. But then I would need know if I can call navigator.vibrate.

My first approach was set a boolean to true after the first touchstart event:

```js
let canVibrate = false;
document.addEventListener("touchstart", () => {
    if (canVibrate) {
        navigator.vibrate(200);
    } else {
        canVibrate = true;
    }
});
```

This first approach works when the user touches with one finger, so probably most of the cases.

However this doesn't work if before pulling of its finger, the user puts down another. In that scenario, the error pops up for every touch done before removing all fingers. And then, it still needs one more touch, as if all these didn't count as an interaction.

Is there any javascript function that lets me know if navigator.vibrate can be called? And if not what are some ways to test it?

Answer (score 0):

As per an example on the [MDN page for touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)

> This calls event.preventDefault() to keep the browser from continuing to process the touch event (this also prevents a mouse event from also being delivered). Then we get the context and pull the list of changed touch points out of the event's TouchEvent.changedTouches property.

To put this in an example you can do something like:

```
let canVibrate = false;
document.addEventListener("touchstart", (event) => {
    if (!canVibrate) {
        canVibrate = true
    }
    navigator.vibrate(200);
});
```

Comment: (1) I don't understand how preventDefault would help me in this case...
I tested it out, and with your solution, chrome gives another error: "Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener due to target being treated as passive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/features/5093566007214080"

Comment: (2) So I added {passive: false} to the document.addEventListener, but then Chrome goes on with a third error: "Ignored attempt to cancel a touchstart event with cancelable=false, for example because scrolling is in progress and cannot be interrupted."

Its also tells that the call to navigator.vibrate was blocked, just as it previously did... So no I don't think preventDefault solves it

Comment: ok try removing the prevent default and just use the answer as is. instead of having an if else like you do in your question

Comment: ...? Well yes of course it will call the function, but it wouldn't vibrate and it would still give out an error. That's not what I'm asking for, I would like not to call navigator.vibrate until the user has interacted enough for the error not to trigger

Comment: try switching to the touchend event

Answer (score -1):

```
if ('vibrate' in navigator) {
  navigator.vibrate(200);
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Google Chrome + Windows laptop. `'vibrate' in navigator` is `true` though obviously my laptop doesn't support this feature.

Comment: @naXastandswithUkraine Interesting finding... Will check tonight

Comment: However the [moz docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/vibrate) do state that the method returns `false` if the method has invalid parameters. So perhaps too if not supported...

Comment: there's no call to `navigator.vibrate()` in the code in your answer. so your MDN docs link is not relevant.